# Native multi select lookup field

Tags: visualforce, lookup, contact, multi-select

I know this is possible using javascript/jquery but I would like to use the native salesforce functionality as it is cleaner and more dynamic. I want to have a single lookup field which is capable of selecting multiple contacts. We have a page in our org -- native to salesforce -- which is a calendar event detail page. On it is a contact lookup field which is capable of selecting multiple users (shown below), and after digging into the source code I can see they are calling sfdc functions (also shown below), I'm just not sure where these are coming from. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]